# Could not get the response on the browser when I have provided external ip and port generated by kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, cloud, microservices

I am using Azure Cloud in deploying a simple spring boot microservices app into Kubernetes. I created a docker image for my spring boot microservices and pushed into private Docker container registry using the Docker CLI. I have created the Kubernetes AKS cluster on Azure Cloud and I have done the process as described by Azure Cloud in setting up the deployment and the service.

My yaml files is as follows

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: holding-details
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  minReadySeconds: 5 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: holding-details
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: holding-details
        image: krajapraveenregistry.azurecr.io/holding-details:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: holding-details
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: holding-details
```

When I ran the `Kubectl apply -f <yaml file name>` I got like below

> Deployment is created and Service is created

When I ran `kubectl get service watch` command, I got like below

```
NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
holding-details   LoadBalancer   10.0.126.95   52.141.219.11   80:30715/TCP   80s
```

In the browser, when I gave url like: http://52.141.219.11:80/holdings/swagger-ui.html, I did not got any output

And also when I gave url like: http://52.141.219.11:30715/holdings/swagger-ui.html, I did not got any output

Comment: so the yamls are fine, i suspect your service doesnt really work. can you connect if you proxy it to the localhost? `kubectl port-forward svc/holding-details 80:80` and try to connect with your browser on `http://127.0.0.1`? also just to confirm are endpoint created (`kubectl get endpoints`)?

Comment: Agreed. Almost definitely a problem with the docker image.

Comment: I have done kubectl port-forward svc/holding-details 80:80 and tried to connect through http://127.0.0.1:80 and http://127.0.0.1:8080 in the browser. I have got the following error:

Comment: E0120 15:32:15.272946    9656 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 80 -> 80: error forwarding port 80 to pod e5cb11b77e5b46e2f6fd3693d08dda87498c971bc5d94666bef94d7b98a
b79d5, uid : exit status 1: 2020/01/20 10:02:16 socat[827] E connect(6, AF=2 127.0.0.1:80, 16): Connection refused

Comment: I have also checked whether there exists any proxy on my system but there is no proxy set on my system

Comment: Steps to reproduce:

Comment: Steps to reproduce:   1) Created a Docker image of microservices in my local. Docker files consists of the following code:  From java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /target/intellect.api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar intellect.api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/intellect.api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

Comment: 2) Pushed the docker file to docker hub. 3) Signed into Azure Cloud . 3) Created a resource group name.4) Created a Container Registry. 5) Created a login server into which I have pushed the docker image of my microservices from docker hub,  attaching the tag as v1.

Comment: When I pulled the docker image from docker hub and ran it, it ran successfully. When I pulled the docker image from Azure Cloud platform and ran it, it ran successfully.

Comment: 6) My yaml file is as follows: apiVersion: apps/v1beta1 kind: Deployment metadata: name: holding-details spec: replicas: 1 strategy: rollingUpdate: maxSurge: 1 maxUnavailable: 1 minReadySeconds: 5 template: metadata:
labels: app: holding-details spec: nodeSelector: "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux containers: - name: holding-details image: krajapraveenregistry.azurecr.io/holding-details:v1 ports: - containerPort: 80 resources: requests: cpu: 250m limits: cpu: 500m

Comment: --- apiVersion: v1 kind: Service metadata: name: holding-details spec: type: LoadBalancer ports: - port: 80 selector: app: holding-details

Comment: 7) Created AKS cluster (Kubernetes cluster)  with ssh keys. Merged the AKS cluster  as current context in .kube\config 8) Kubectl get nodes. 9) Then I have given the following command: kubectl apply -f C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\holding_details\holding-details.yaml

Comment: 10)  On giving the the above command which is: kubectl apply -f C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\holding_details\holding-details.yaml I have got the following:  deployment created and service created. 11) Then I gave the following command : kubectl get service holding-details --watch

Comment: NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        AGE
holding-details   LoadBalancer   10.0.135.217   52.154.165.2   80:30639/TCP   84m

Comment: When I gave like: 52.154.165.2:80/holdings/swagger-ui.html , I am not getting any response on the browser. I also gave like http: 10.0.135.217:80/ holdings/swagger-ui.html, I did got any response. When I gave like 52.154.165.2:30639/holdings/swagger-ui.html , I am not getting any response on the browser. I also gave like http: 10.0.135.217:30639/ holdings/swagger-ui.html, I did got any response.

Comment: Please note that out running url in the local system is:  http://localhost:8080/holdings/swagger-ui.html

Comment: Can you please help me on this regarding why I could not get the response on my browser with external ip and port generated by kubectl

Comment: Please include steps to reproduce in question, not in comments.